# Garry's mod library.so not found

Tags: steam, technical-issues, linux, garrys-mod

I already asked this question on Stack Overflow, but someone told me to ask it here.
So *Garry's Mod* is not working because some libraries were not found.

OS: Linux Mint 21.1 Kernel: 6.2.0

I apparently meet all the recommended specs for playing *Garry's Mod*, so it's likely not hardware-related, especially because it works perfectly fine on Windows.

I tried starting the game on Steam, but it loaded for 1 second, and the window just crashed with no error message.

What I did is running it in the terminal, at `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/GarrysMod` I ran `./hl2_linux` which told me that a library is not working.

> Error: ./hl2_linux: error while loading shared libraries: libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What I tried (1):

So I did `find / -name path/to/library` and put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:path/to/library into ~/.bashrc` and did `./hl2_linux` again, and another library was missing, repeat. But after doing that like 8 times, nano ended up breaking and the game just got a segmentation fault so I deleted that line in .bashrc.

What I tried (2):

A couple of things, deleting the *Garry's Mod* folder, deleting Proton, deleting Sniper, none of these worked.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't have Mint to play along unfortunately, but rather than global fixes try app-specific: e.g. [using launch options](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/747rru/how_can_i_add_that_ld_library_path_to_my_launch/?rdt=60166). This should help keep the fixes from screwing up e.g. `nano`.

Comment: Idk if verifying game files would help? If it's a game file that should help, but I am guessing this is an OS specific file.

Comment: Guess what, I first thought the problem WAS Proton but it wasn't even enabled on GMod, so I enabled it, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for the "TCMalloc" library.  You're in luck: Linux Mint has that library in its repository, so you don't need to go through the pain of dealing with TCMalloc's build system.

Open up your package manager (I think Mint uses Synaptic), and install the "libtcmalloc-minimal4" package.